# C# Do something after document loaded

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to do something after the document have completely load... I dont want to use WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event, so please don't suggest me this.

I tried 2 ways to do it but they not work. Can someone tell me what I doing wrong?

Example 1

```
wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
while(wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { }
richtextdocument.Text = wb.DocumentText;
```

Example 2

```
wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
while(wb.isBusy == true) { }
richtextdocument.Text = wb.DocumentText;
```

Comment: What's wrong with 'DocumentCompleted' event?

Comment: could you please tell us why you don't want to use `DocumentCompleted`? Checking if loading completed doesn't seem to be the best approach. two samples you've provided will result in a lot of cpu usage (as thread is not put into sleep state, so it will check as many time per second as possible).

Comment: "I dont want to use WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event" - Why not ?

Comment: Because I will make a lot of times check if document completed for different things. So lets say the first time I will want to Print something the next time I will want to do something else etc. How I can write all this to one method?

Comment: I will use timer (cause of the cpu usage problem that MaciekTalaksa said) if one of this 2 examples work.

Comment: Do you want to print something else during the WebBrowser loading its content?

Comment: No exactly.. The first time when page loaded I will save some information, then i will load other page and print some information.. this process may be used a lot of times for different webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are dealing with here is trying to call an inherently asynchronous method synchronously.

As you mentioned in the comments to your question that the reason for not using `DocumentCompleted` is that you will need to use that event for other purposes, what I suggest you do is to use the `DocumentCompleted` event, coupled with a private class boolean flag to determine if this is the special case of `DocumentCompleted` or not.

```
private bool wbNeedsSpecialAction; //when you need to call the special case of Navigate() set this flag to true

public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();         
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
}

void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (wbNeedsSpecialAction)
    {
        richtextdocument.Text = wb.DocumentText;
        wbNeedsSpecialAction = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //other cases of using DocumentCompleted...
    }
}

public void Browse()
{
    wbNeedsSpecialAction = true; //make sure the event is treated differently
    wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

This will still allow you to control other cases within the event handler.

You must take special care to ensure that your user is not able to trigger another call to `Navigate()` *before* this 'special action' page finishes loading, otherwise it may *steal* the special case event. One way could be to block the UI until the page finishes loading, e.g.:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use timer to validate document load state.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                richTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {application.doevents }
```